# CRM 2011 data missing in service

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am adding a service reference in VS.NET 2010 using

```
http://[orgname].api.crm.dynamics.com/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl
```

URL but it doesn't get the entities from the CRM, just get rest of the information

so how do it add reference to it, i have checked

http://bingsoft.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/crm-2011-beta-discovery-and-web-service-urls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the crmsvcutil tool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681561.aspx

Comment: It looks like you've got the wrong link. Should be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx. Your's pointing do Dynamics CRM 4

Comment: but it is still a work around, why it is not working when i am adding it as service reference?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.abodit.com/2011/03/crmsvcutil-exe-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-online-problem/) you can find the steps (they are pretty straightforward) you need to follow to work with your CRM Online instance. You use the `crmsvcutil.exe` tool to generate the metadata of your organization.